# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_ProductsComparsion after adding a composite key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I try to add a product to the comparison list but if a list with this `Id` already exists, then I'm getting an error:

*PostgresException: 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_ProductsComparsion".*

How can I fix this?

I added a composite key, but it still doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

**Models**

```
public class ProductComparsion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid SessionId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductToCompare> ProductsToCompare { get; set; }
}

public class ProductToCompare
{
    public int ProductComparsionId { get; set; }
    public ProductComparsion ProductComparsion { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }        
}
```

**AppDbContextModelProvider**

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductComparsion>(typeBuiler =>
        {
            typeBuiler.ToTable(nameof(AppDbContext.ProductsComparsion));
            typeBuiler.HasKey(z => z.Id);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductToCompare>(typeBuilder =>
        {
            typeBuilder.ToTable(nameof(AppDbContext.ProductsToCompare));
            typeBuilder.HasKey(z => new { z.ProductId, z.ProductComparsionId });
            typeBuilder.HasOne(z => z.ProductComparsion).WithMany(z => z.ProductsToCompare).HasForeignKey(z => z.ProductComparsionId);
            // Composite key:
            typeBuilder.HasOne(z => z.Product).WithMany().HasForeignKey(z => z.ProductId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        });
```

**AddProductToComparsionList**

```
    public async Task<ProductComparsionVM> AddProductToComparsionList(List<int> productIds, int listId = 0)
    {
        var comparsionList = await _dbContext.ProductsComparsion
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(z => z.Id.Equals(listId));

        var products = _dbContext.Products.Include(z => z.ProductCategories);

        foreach (var productId in productIds)
        {
            comparsionList.ProductsToCompare.Add(new ProductToCompare { ProductId = productId });
        }                          

        // Error: can't add item with existing 'listId'
        await _dbContext.AddAsync(comparsionList);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: so do you add the composite key before or after migration?

Comment: if it's after, you may need to delete previous migration and generate dbcontext again and migrate to database one more time